# How to repair a shot hfs+ partition?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, hfs+

I have a Macbookpro with a 450GB HFS+ partition and a 50GB Ubuntu 13.04 setup. I started Ubuntu and wanted to mount the HFS+ partition rw - and did it all wrong: I wrote (from my memory)

```
sudo hpmount rw /dev/sda1
```

I know I got it all wrong here. But the response was something like, "Do you really want to write to this volume, Data corruption could occur... (yes/no)", I typed yes, it complained about a missing block at 0 or something and said it could not do it.
I think, later on I ran a fsck on the volume and it did not find errors.

Then, in nautilus the drive previously known as 'Macintosh HD' became a '450GB Harddisk' (or similar). When I tried to mount it there I got an error (from hfutils, I think). When I wanted to reboot, Ubuntu hang and I had to reset.
Upon resetting, Refind (efi boot manager) does not start, instead I boot directly into Macintosh recovery console. I have no backup (I had until yesterday, when I was so sure about my system's sanity, that I used it for the purpose that led to this situation).
Disk manager shows me some partitions, including the mac partition, but does not recognize it as such.

Judge me! But could anyone tell what it was I did to my drive and what I could do to recover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using System Recovery's Disk Utility I was able to get the partition to become readable again. I bought a Firewire cable and used a different mac to access my notebook in target disk mode. I could then copy all my files to another usb disk.
Then I had to repartition and reinstall the OS. what was left was to copy my data back. All was well, lost a whole day in the process, but that's still a good price considering my stupidity.